# App login screen prompts user input despite already logging in

Tags: android, android-layout

I've made a login screen on Android.

After the client enters their name and password, they are directed to another screen via intent.

However, there is a problem after signing in and then pressing the back button on the phone to leave the app. When opening the application for a second time after doing so, it again returns to the login screen.

How can I prevent this from occurring so it does not repeatedly ask for login information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the task when calling the next activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the backstack and on pressing back, your application will close.

Answer (score 1):

add `android:nohistory="true"` for `LoginActivity` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

add `finish()` in your `LoginActivity`'s `onStop()` method.